# Uneven voltage in series-connected AGM battery storage system

Tags: lead-acid, battery-storage

I've been working with a 48V storage system composed of 4 AGM batteries 250 Ah connected in series, all new from factory. The charger stops charging at 2.45V per cell, with an output voltage of 58.8VDC. During the setup phase, I equalized the voltage of all batteries. At 50% state of charge, the voltage difference between the batteries is within the acceptable range of 10-20mV (reference limit is 100mV). However, as the voltage approaches the cut off point, I'm noticing significant differences in voltage between the batteries.

Here are the observations:

```
**Battery 1: 15.06 VDC**
Battery 2: 14.30 VDC
Battery 3: 14.36 VDC
Battery 4: 14.72 VDC
Total: 58.44 VDC
```

One battery's voltage is higher than the cut-off voltage, which could be due to differences in impedance resistance among the batteries. I am seeking guidance on how to address this issue without compromising the capacity, safety, and reliability of the storage system.

Comment: Does the charger not carry out balancing during charging?

Comment: no, batteries are just connected in series

Comment: Well... there's your answer. Even tiny differences will cause them to get more and more unbalanced over time.

Comment: I'm 10 times below the recommended max difference between batteries. I connected the four batteries alone in parallel for a week. I cannot do better than that. Can I ?

Comment: Unless you want to be manually balancing your batteries periodically you need to get a charger which knows how to balance them itself. If you've tried to balance them yourself already and not had much luck then it's possible that one or more of them have already been (slightly) damaged.

Comment: "I'm 10 times below the recommended max difference between batteries." - The max difference here is 15.06-14.3 i.e. 0.76V. I really don't believe the max recommended difference between four 12V batteries is 7.6V.

Comment: Try equalizing the voltages when the batteries are fully charged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the technical and 'infrastructural' challenge of putting batteries/cells in a series string:  keeping them at the same or at least similar state-of-charge (SoC).

By themselves, when cycled through a few discharge/recharge cycles, cells will "wander away from each other" in terms of their SoC, because each battery ("monoblock" if we're talking about a 6-cell 12V Lead-Acid battery) is a little bit different, and each cell within the battery/monoblock is a little bit different.  It's due to differences in the electrolyte concentration, copper losses in the conductors both within and linking each battery/monoblock, impurities in all the current-carrying materials (anode & cathode, electrolyte, etc), small temerature differences between batteries/monoblocs, and so on.

BTW, knowing the SoC (e.g. as a percentage %) is only roughly indicated by terminal voltage.  If a current is being drawn from a battery or recharged into a battery, then its internal resistance causes the terminal voltage to be lower (or higher) than its open-circuit/no-load voltage.  There's also the 'refractory period' after drawing a load from the battery, where after you stop drawing, you'll see a 'recovery' of terminal voltage (it's all in the chemicals).  In the case of Lead-Acid batteries, ascertaining SoC needs to ideally be taken by a hydrometer, or by 'counting coulombs', so measuring both current and voltage and integrating those over time to count 'energy'.  Simply measuring terminal voltage is not an accurate indicator of SoC.

The problem with the individual batteries/monoblocs diverging in their SoC is multiple:

- Some head toward a low SoC, some will head toward a higher SoC
- Then under load, the lower SoC batteries will reach their lower limit of discharge terminal voltage, so you need to stop drawing power, otherwise  you'll damage those lower-SoC cells/batteries.
- But then you still have some batteries with plenty of charge left in them, even though you now need to stop and recharge the whole string.
- So you start charing.  The batteries with the lowest SoC accept all the charge you can give them until they're full, but
- the batteries which started recharge with the higher SoC reach 100% charge sooner, so to not damage them by over-charging you need to stop charging, but then the batteries which started with the lower-SoC aren't fully charged yet.

This is the conundrum that "cell balancing" overcomes (or battery/monoblock balancing).  It's additional circuitry that looks at the terminal voltage on each cell/monobloc/battery, and realises that during recharge some have reached 100% and need ty have the recharge current stopped, by shunting it around them; or, you start the recharge cycle by lowering the SoC of the higher-SoC cells first to bring them all back into alignment with the lower-SoC cells, then you can recharge them all together.  There are multiple techniques for achieving this, depending on Reasons.

What you need is a recharger which understands what kind (chemistry) of battery it's recharging, and has connections not just to the top & bottom of the series string, but each cell/battery/monoblock along the string, and can apply 'cell balanacing' during recharge.

Comment: Lead-acid is tolerant to trickle charging when full, right? For standby use, could you just equalize them at 100% by allowing some overcharge?

Comment: Correct, lead-acid is much more tolerant of ‘trickle charging’ (Lithium rechargeables aren’t, their SoA is way more constrained), and if you have the opportunity to (a) full charge, and then (b) do an ‘equalisation’ charge to bring up the lower-SoC outliers, then sure.  But you can’t operate in a partial SoC (see-saw-ing SoC up & down) for very long before the above-mentioned problem comes back, and the longer you remain in a partial-SoC state the more cell/monoblock divergence occurs, and the more effort & time you need to spend bringing them back into line with each other.